# class org.apache.ignite.IgniteClientDisconnectedException

Tags: caching, gridgain, ignite

I am trying to populate a Gridgain cache which is running on a cluster on other machine. I'm getting ClientDisconnectedException while calling method on a Gridgain Cache and getting this after calling put method on the Cache.

Here is my cache Configuration:

```
// DPH cache
        CacheConfiguration<K,V> DPHCacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<>(DPH_CACHE);
        DPHCacheCfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED); // Default.
        DPHCacheCfg.setIndexedTypes(String.class, DPH.class);
        DPHCacheCfg.setOffHeapMaxMemory(10 * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L);
        DPHCacheCfg.setMemoryMode(CacheMemoryMode.ONHEAP_TIERED);
        FifoEvictionPolicy evctPolicy = new FifoEvictionPolicy();
        DPHCacheCfg.setEvictionPolicy(evctPolicy);
```

Her is how I put data in The Cache:

DPHCache.put(K, V); where V is some object. After certain number of puts, I am having the below exception.

```
avax.cache.CacheException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteClientDisconnectedException: Operation has been cancelled (client node disconnected).
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheUtils.convertToCacheException(GridCacheUtils.java:1615)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.cacheException(IgniteCacheProxy.java:1955)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.put(IgniteCacheProxy.java:1155)
    at com.elsevier.elssie.datafabric.LoadQuetzal.populateDPH(LoadQuetzal.java:246)
    at com.elsevier.elssie.datafabric.LoadQuetzal.main(LoadQuetzal.java:163)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:294)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteClientDisconnectedException: Operation has been cancelled (client node disconnected).
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils$14.apply(IgniteUtils.java:829)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils$14.apply(IgniteUtils.java:827)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteClientDisconnectedCheckedException: Operation has been cancelled (client node disconnected).
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMvccManager.disconnectedError(GridCacheMvccManager.java:406)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMvccManager.onDisconnected(GridCacheMvccManager.java:382)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheSharedContext.onDisconnected(GridCacheSharedContext.java:151)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.onDisconnected(GridCacheProcessor.java:934)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.onDisconnected(IgniteKernal.java:3023)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$4.onDiscovery(GridDiscoveryManager.java:588)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$MessageWorker.notifyDiscovery(ClientImpl.java:2058)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$MessageWorker.notifyDiscovery(ClientImpl.java:2039)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$MessageWorker.body(ClientImpl.java:1435)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens when all server nodes stop. You should check their logs to understand what exactly happened.

Also note that the client will reconnect automatically when at least one server is back. `IgniteClientDisconnectedException` has the `reconnectFuture()` method which returns the future that will be completed when the reconnection happens, so you can block the client until the cluster is functional.